# SqlServer without windows authentication mode

Tags: sql-server

I am using SqlServer 2008 R2 express edition. 
Is it possible to run SqlServer without windows authentication mode?

Comment: I think you can only choose between "Windows authentication only" and "Mixed mode". At least that's what the manual says: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: Why do you want to? Why do you need this? As gbn correctly states, you cannot run without Windows authentication, but there may be another way to acheive what you need.

Comment: I would not like to give windows users to access sqlserver database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you always have Windows Authentication.
The only option is whether you want SQL Server mode **as well** or not

Guessing at the reason for this, see [Securing SQL Server database from Domain Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16817793/27535) for some tips on locking down a SQL Server installation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, connect to server under Windows authentication , click Properties -> Security -> choose SQL Server and Windows authentication mode

Comment: OP is asking "*without* windows authentication mode"

Comment: Is it possible to run only SqlServer mode?

Comment: without windows authentication mode means Sql Server Mode, or I'm not right?

Answer (score 0):

Without Windows mode you can directly access on server where your database is located using your id and password.