# SqlServer mixed mode restrict windows users

Tags: sql-server

I am running SqlServer 2008 R2 express edition as mixed mode. Is it possible to prevent windows users to access database or remove them form database.

Comment: Why not ask properly the first time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046370/sqlserver-without-windows-authentication-mode Simple permissions will do it unless everyone runs as an admin...

Comment: Actually I don’t want to give windows user to access database anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users have to be explicitly given permission to the server and database.  Simply, by not granting access, Windows users do not have access.  You can explicitly restrict access with:

DENY CONNECT SQL TO [domain\user]